# Updating the repository location for an existing SVN checkout

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Consider the scenario of an SVN server with a dynamic IP: I check out a repository from `svn://192.168.1.10/Repo`. Then I make a bunch of changes. Meanwhile, the IP on the server has rolled and it's now located at `svn://192.168.1.12/Repo`. How can I tell my existing checkout to update from/commit to that location?

Answer using TortoiseSVN would be preferred, but I can hold my own on the command prompt if needs be.

Comment: Since the address is a local one, I would look at fixing the address on that machine so that it doesn't change. Either map the MAC address of the network card of that machine to a static address in your router, or assign a static ip address to the machine in its network control panel. Then you don't have to deal with this problem ever again. Also, have you considered just using the hostname instead? ie. "svn://svnserver/Repo"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on root folder and choose **Relocate** in TortoiseSVN options.